# Does background-color by default take on the entirety of the viewport if set on the body tag?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<body class="page">
</body>
```

and tied to that selector, the following rule:

```
.page {
    background-color: #2A2C2F;
}
```

[image]

From what the above picture shows, the `body` element takes up its containing elements' width (naturally, as it is a `block` level element) and has no height. Even with this being the case however, I see that the entirety of the viewport takes on the `background-color` that I have set. According to [this freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-background-color-tutorial-how-to-change-a-div-background-color-explained-with-code-examples/) article, the `background-color` only affects the content area and padding of an element (although I wonder if we can change that with the `box-sizing` rule).

Why is it that even without a height, the viewport seemingly takes on the `background-color`?

Comment: Then what do you think viewport is?

Comment: @George The way I understand it is that the viewport is the part of the document that is visible which I suppose is not necessarily the same as the `body`. However, why does the `background-color` still affect it if I am only setting it on the `body`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes, if the `<html>` tag has no background color.

From [CSS-tricks:](https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/)

> In the absence of a background on the html element, the body background will cover the page. If there is a background on the html element, the body background behaves just like any other element.

You can also read more about it from [the spec on CSS backgrounds](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#background).

---

Consider the following two snippets:

1. No background color on `<html>`, body background color stretches to fill the [canvas](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#canvas).

```css
body {
  background-color: #2a2c2f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
content here
```

2. Background color on `<html>`, body background color is restricted to the content within the body tag.

```css
html {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #2a2c2f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
content here
```

Comment: The spec is at paragraphs 3 and 4 of [CSS 2.2 14.2 The background](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#background). Specifically the body background is propagated to the *canvas*, not the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Alohci.